# Where can I find tax year 2020 IRA contribution limits?

Tags: united-states, ira, irs, contribution, limits

Where can I find tax year 2020 IRA contribution limits? IRS website shows info for only 2022 and 2021.
There are other websites that have this info but I want to be certain by confirming with IRS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/plan-participant-employee/retirement-topics-ira-contribution-limits

This goes back to 2015:

> For 2022, 2021, 2020 and 2019, the total contributions you make each
> year to all of your traditional IRAs  and Roth IRAs can't be more
> than:
>
> -$6,000 ($7,000 if you're age 50 or older), or
> -If less, your taxable compensation for the year
>
> For 2018, 2017, 2016 and 2015, the total contributions you make each
> year to all of your traditional IRAs and Roth IRAs can't be more than:
>
> - $5,500 ($6,500 if you're age 50 or older), or
> - If less, your taxable compensation for the year

This table goes back even farther:

https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-tege/cola-table.pdf